# How do we use packages installed from vcpkg?

Tags: c++, cmake, vcpkg

I'm installing packages (`aws-sdk`, `jsoncpp`, ..) from `vcpkg` into my `cmake` project. But I'm having hard time trying to use them in my project, it's really difficult to figure out how to get `cmake` to find the installed packages, somehow I managed to add the target path for `AWS-SDK`, but I'm finding it difficult for other packages. So my question is, how do we get `cmake` to find packages installed using `vcpkg`?

Here is how my `CMakeLists.txt` file looks like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
project(compiler LANGUAGES CXX)

include_directories(${JSONCPP_INCLUDE_DIRS})

find_package(AWSSDK REQUIRED COMPONENTS s3)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} compiler.cpp)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${AWSSDK_LINK_LIBRARIES})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${JSONCPP_LINK_LIBRARIES})
```

And here is the docker file where I'm installing `vcpkg` and then these packages.

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

WORKDIR /app

RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get install ffmpeg \
  g++ \
  git \
  curl \
  zip \
  unzip \
  tar \
  openssl \
  gcc \
  cmake \
  zlib1g-dev \
  libcurl4-openssl-dev \
  libssl-dev \
  uuid-dev \
  libpulse-dev \
  make \
  pkg-config -y

RUN git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg.git && \
  ./vcpkg/bootstrap-vcpkg.sh
RUN ./vcpkg/vcpkg install "aws-sdk-cpp[s3]" --recurse
RUN ./vcpkg/vcpkg install "jsoncpp"
COPY . .

RUN DIR=compiler && mkdir ${DIR} && cd ${DIR} && \
  cmake .. -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake && \
  cmake --build .

CMD cd compiler && ls -a && ./compiler
```

Comment: Well, to start, you're missing a `find_package()` for `jsoncpp`. Make sure you're using the right variables in your `target_link_libraries()` commands.

Comment: Hey @nega I'm very new to cmake, can you please refer me to any resources where I can learn to identify & add right variables in target_link_libraries()?